# Step Functions, using parallel and choosing what step going to execute by a variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is there any way to choose what steps going to execute inside a parallel state?
Filtering by a variable ou something?

Or is there a way to use choice state and send to multiples tasks?

Answer (score 0):

All branch inside parallel state executed and there is no way to control it by only using Parallel state. As you mentioned choice state is the best bet to handle it. If you have a list of tasks and some condition to determine which one to execute, then the best way is to use Map state and Choice state inside it to make it conditional.